# Can not use .htaccess file to define redirect in Apache server for Angular

Tags: angular, apache, docker, .htaccess

I deploy application developed by Angular to Apache Web server in Docker container. Since it is SPA I need to redirect all requests with different routes to index.html.

I try to solve it.

1. I change `apache2.conf` file

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

2. I add `.htaccess`  file to the folder where `index.html` is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d

    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

3. Then I reload server with command `/etc/init.d/apache2 reload`
   It was **not helpful**
4. I stop container and start it again. **Not help**
5. I commit container and re-run it from new image. **Not help**

**Can somebody explain me what's wrong and how to use .htaccess in correct way?**

Comment: Is rewrite module enabled on server?, Conditional '<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>', this will just fail silently if not enabled.

Comment: @gmfm I don't know how to check, whether module enable or not and how to turn it on!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2